# In 互联网与制造业的关系已经越来越紧密, why is 已经越来越 not incorrect?

Tags: grammar

This is a HSK6 病句 ("faulty sentence") question:

> 1. 申报专利的程序很复杂，需要当事人携带多项资料，办理多项手续，**和很大的耐心**，能不能成功还不一定。
> 2. 城市桥梁管理条例草案已被通过，这意味着，以后桥下空间将允许停放机动车。
> 3. 本县乡镇间第一季度项目合作的签约仪式昨天举行，主管合作的副县长代表县长发了言并当场转达了县长的祝贺，县长因故缺席。
> 4. 互联网与制造业的关系**已经越来越**紧密，工业互联网是生产运营环节，互联网金融是货币资金融通环节，都是围绕制造业来运行的。
>
> <sub>HSK规范教程6上，p.131 [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWvxA.jpg)</sub>

When answering this question, I chose 1. because 和 doesn't seem to make any sense (很大的耐心 doesn't seem to pair with anything, but it should because there's a 和).  I nearly chose the fourth sentence because 已经越来越 seems like a contradiction.  It still feels wrong to me, as if it should either be 已经紧密 or 越来越紧密.

**Question**: In 互联网与制造业的关系已经越来越紧密, why is 已经越来越 not incorrect?

The correct answer in the book is 1., with no justification given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the answer key say so?

I think "已经越来越" is correct. 已经 is an adverb associated with perfect-perfective action. 越来越 is an adverb, meaning been gradually intensified. It's similar to progressive perfective (has been more and more). These two are in fact often used together either colloquially or in writing.

"互联网与制造业的关系已经越来越紧密"

"工业互联网是生产运营环节"

"互联网金融是货币资金融通环节"

These are 3 clauses. The problem is that "都是围绕制造业来运行的" does not have a subject.

---

In 1:

predicate 需要

object 1 which is a clause  当事人携带多项资料，办理多项手续 Its internal structure is S+V1O1+V2O2. This is a complex sentence.

object 2 which is a noun phrase   很大的耐心

和 connects a object clause and a NP object. Grammatically it's ok, but do reads awkward to me.

It's more natural to me if 很大的耐心 is included in the object clause, as 需要当事人携带多项资料，办理多项手续，有很大的耐心。

---

My answer could be inaccurate since we don't study much Mandarin grammar at grade school. Just speak as a native speaker and a linguistic hobbyist. Welcome discussion from any angle.

Answer (score 1):

> 申报专利的程序很复杂，需要当事人携带多项资料，办理多项手续，和很大的耐心，能不能成功还不一定。

The answer should be the first sentence. It's not because of 和, but the logic. "申报专利的***程序很复杂***" The topic is 程序很复杂(complexity of the procedures). 携带多项资料 and 办理多项手续 are relevant to procedure. Well, 很大的耐心 isn't part of procedure.

已经越来越 seems also improper. In spoken, it seems ok sometimes. 了 works better than 已经 here. E.g. 越来越好了;她越来越漂亮了.

Answer (score 1):

> 已经越来越

The expression 已经越来越 is ok, being also widely used. See it as something like "it is already ... and it is becoming even more so." It's even in my dictionary:

[image]

> 需要当事人携带多项资料，办理多项手续，和很大的耐心

I can see in this phrase at least two mistakes.

1. **Subject-verb-object structure incorrect**
   Three things are needed, introduced by 需要:
   a) 携带多项资料 (subject:当事人, verb: 携带, object: 多项资料);
   b) 办理多项手续 (the subject is still 当事人 and there is no need to repeat it, verb: 办理, object: 多项手续);
   c) 很大的耐心 (**no verb here**, and it's wrong).
2. **Wrong punctuation**
   It should be 需要当事人 "**A、B 和 C**" and not "A，B，和 C".

The correct phrase could be:

> 当事人需要携带多项资料、办理多项手续和很大的耐心